# Why would a call to fmt.Sprint(e) inside the Error() method result in an infinite loop?

Tags: go

I am going through ["A Tour of Go"](https://tour.golang.org/methods/20) tutorial.

I would like to check the answer to this question:

> **Note:** a call to `fmt.Sprint(e)` inside the `Error` method will send
>   the program into an infinite loop. You can avoid this by converting
>   `e` first: `fmt.Sprint(float64(e))`. Why?

I believe this is because when the `Sprint` function is called, since the error is non-nil, the `Error function()` will again be called, and so forth, resulting in an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks, I got caught up on this here: https://tour.golang.org/methods/20

Answer (score 98, accepted):

`fmt.Sprint(e)` will call `e.Error()` to convert the value `e` to a `string`. If the `Error()` method calls `fmt.Sprint(e)`, then the program recurses until out of memory.

You can break the recursion by converting the `e` to a value without a `String` or `Error` method.

Comment: Isn't it enough to convert e to a type which may have a String/Error method that doesn't recurse infinitely?

Comment: Yes, `fmt.Sprintf("cannot Sqrt negative number: %f", e)` works

Comment: But why does it try to call `e.Error()` to do the conversion? If I try to make it implement the Stringer interface, it doesn't try to call it. What makes it seek out to the `Error()` method?

Comment: @hytromo In [fmt/print.go](https://golang.org/src/fmt/print.go?s=7053:7089), `Sprint` eventually leads to `handleMethods` with a verb of `v`. The [switch inside handleMethods](https://golang.org/src/fmt/print.go#L614) checks if the argument satisfies the error type before Stringer, resulting in the `Error()` method being called instead of `String()`.

Answer (score 17):

fmt.Sprint(e) will invoke the following piece of codes from "fmt/print.go"

```
switch verb {
    case 'v', 's', 'x', 'X', 'q':
        // Is it an error or Stringer?
        // The duplication in the bodies is necessary:
        // setting handled and deferring catchPanic
        // must happen before calling the method.
        switch v := p.arg.(type) {
        case error:
            handled = true
            defer p.catchPanic(p.arg, verb, "Error")
            p.fmtString(v.Error(), verb)
            return

        case Stringer:
            handled = true
            defer p.catchPanic(p.arg, verb, "String")
            p.fmtString(v.String(), verb)
            return
        }
    }
```

As error case appears first, v.Error() will be executed. Endless loop here!

Comment: [https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17:src/fmt/print.go;l=617](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17:src/fmt/print.go;l=617)