# An infinite loop produced by fmt.Sprint(e) inside the Error method

Tags: go

According to fortyforty's reply to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474907/error-infinite-loop):

> `fmt.Sprint(e)` will call `e.Error()` to convert the value `e` to a
>   `string`. If the `Error()` method calls `fmt.Sprint(e)`, then the
>   program recurses until out of memory.
>
> You can break the recursion by converting the `e` to a value without a
>   `String` or `Error` method.

This is still confusing to me. Why does fmt.Sprint(e) call e.Error() instead of String()? I tried using the Stringer interface, this is my code:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "math"
)

type NegativeSqrt float64

func (e NegativeSqrt) Error() string {
  fmt.Printf(".")
  return fmt.Sprint(e)
}

func (e NegativeSqrt) String() string {
  return fmt.Sprintf("%f", e)
}

func Sqrt(x float64) (float64, error) {
  if x < 0 {
    return 0, NegativeSqrt(x)
  }
  return math.Sqrt(x), nil
}

func main() {
  fmt.Println(Sqrt(2))
  fmt.Println(Sqrt(-2))
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems it's explained [directly](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/2ed57a8cd86cec36b8370fb16d450e5a29a9375f/src/pkg/fmt/print.go#L639) is source of fmt package:

```
// Is it an error or Stringer?
// The duplication in the bodies is necessary:
// setting handled and deferring catchPanic
// must happen before calling the method.
```

And than [Error()](http://golang.org/src/fmt/print.go?s=6663:6699#L714) or [String()](http://golang.org/src/fmt/print.go?s=6663:6699#L720) is called.

What it means is that first [error.Error()](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#error) is called to produce string, which is than once again processed and is printed as string.

Whether `error` has method `String` is irrelevant here. The question is why `NegativeSqrt` is printed with one method and not the other. Type `NegativeSqrt` implements both `fmt.Stringer` and `error` interfaces so it's up to the implementation of `fmt` package which of interfaces should be used to get `string` from `NegativeSqrt` (since [fmt.Sprint](http://golang.org/src/fmt/print.go?s=6663:6699#L237) takes its parameters by `interface{}`).

To illustrate this consider this example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type NegativeSqrt float64

func (e NegativeSqrt) Error() string {
    return ""
}

func (e NegativeSqrt) String() string {
    return ""
}

func check(val interface{}) {
    switch val.(type) {
    case fmt.Stringer:
        fmt.Println("It's stringer")
    case error:
        fmt.Println("It's error")
    }
}

func check2(val interface{}) {
    switch val.(type) {
    case error:
        fmt.Println("It's error")
    case fmt.Stringer:
        fmt.Println("It's stringer")
    }
}

func main() {
    var v NegativeSqrt
    check(v)
    check2(v)
}
```

Executing this gives:

```
% go run a.go
It's stringer
It's error
```

This is because in Go type switch behaves just like normal switch, so [order of cases matters](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#switch).

Comment: After your "edit", this answer now explains why we have that behaviour, thanks.

Comment: _**Edit:** I fixed the link. The given link was not working. give links by pointing to a commit, not the master, it can change._

Answer (score 5):

Because the type is `error` and the interface of `error` is

```
  type error interface{
     Error() string
  }
```

every `error` must have an `Error() string` method but does not have to have a `String() string` method. That why is logic to check first the `Error()` method.

Comment: Tomasz Kłak's answer is also brilliant but this one explains why it is implemented this way.

Comment: I don't think that this question is on topic/correct.

Answer (score 1):

Let me expand tumdum's finding for better clarity.

I'll jump from a call to call to show how we go into loop.

We start from the exercise's

```
func (e NegativeSqrt) Error() string {
  fmt.Printf(".")
  return fmt.Sprint(e)
}
```

Which delivers us to a line 237 of the [fmt/print.go](https://golang.org/src/fmt/print.go):

```
func Sprint(a ...interface{}) string
```

Inside the function, our next jump is on line 239:

```
p.doPrint(a, false, false)
```

We arrive to line 1261:

```
func (p *pp) doPrint(a []interface{}, addspace, addnewline bool) {
```

Inside that function, we'll jump, with our `error` argument, through line 1273:

```
prevString = p.printArg(arg, 'v', 0)
```

We arrive at a huge core monster function at line 738:

```
func (p *pp) printArg(arg interface{}, verb rune, depth int) (wasString bool) {
```

Inside that, you can see a large `switch case` switch. `error` goes in the `default` section as it is deemed to be a non-trivial type.

Which delivers us to line 806 with the call to `handleMethods()`:

```
if handled := p.handleMethods(verb, depth); handled {
```

We arrive at  line 688:

```
func (p *pp) handleMethods(verb rune, depth int) (handled bool) {
```

Inside of that function, on line 724, call to `Error()` happens, which completes the loop:

```
p.printArg(v.Error(), verb, depth)
```