# Accessing Golang struct that implements error interface causes function to never return

Tags: go, struct

## Background

I'm unmarshalling JSON data from an HTTP API to the following Golang structs:

```
type ResponseBody struct {
    Version string `json:"jsonrpc"`
    Result  Result `json:"result"`
    Error   Error  `json:"error"`
    Id      int    `json:"id"`
}

type Result struct {
    Random struct {
        Data           interface{} `json:"data"`
        CompletionTime string      `json:"completionTime"`
    } `json:"random"`
    BitsUsed      int `json:"bitsUsed"`
    BitsLeft      int `json:"bitsLeft"`
    RequestsLeft  int `json:"requestsLeft"`
    AdvisoryDelay int `json:"advisoryDelay"`
}

type Error struct {
    Code    int    `json:"code"`
    Message string `json:"message"`
    Data    []int  `json:"data,omitempty"`
}
```

and I've implemented the error interface for `Error` as follows:

```
func (e Error) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Error: %+v", e)
}
```

Relevant code so far:

```
func Request(method string, params interface{}) (Result, error) {
    // `error` in return types is _not_ a typo

    body, err := json.Marshal(RequestBody{Version: "2.0", Params: params, Method: method, Id: 1})
    if err != nil {
        return Result{}, err
    }

    resp, err := http.Post(endpoint, "application/json-rpc", bytes.NewReader(body))
    if err != nil {
        return Result{}, fmt.Errorf("Request failed, error was %s", err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    text, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return Result{}, fmt.Errorf("Failed to read response into memory, error was: %s", err)
    }

    if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
        var errorMessage Error
        if err := json.Unmarshal(text, &errorMessage); err != nil {
            return Result{}, Error{
                Code:    409,
                Message: fmt.Sprintf("Client could not decode JSON error response, received %s, error was: %s", text, err),
                Data:    []int{},
            }
        }
        return Result{}, errorMessage
    }

    response := ResponseBody{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(text, &response); err != nil {
        return Result{}, fmt.Errorf("Failed to JSON-decode response body, received %s from source, error was: %s", text, err)
    }

    return response.Result, response.Error
}
```

## Issue

The following code hangs indefinitely on a successful call without panicking:

```
// `body` here is just any old struct
result, err := Request("generateIntegers", body)
if err != nil {
    return []int{}, err  // hangs here
}
```

In fact, the code always hangs when I invoke `err`. No panic is raised and no error is returned - it is simply frozen[1].

[1] Strictly speaking, it causes a stack overflow error, but that's because the function never returns and so the deferred `resp.Body.Close()` in `Request` never gets called.

It gets weirder. Adding the following debugging lines:

```
response := ResponseBody{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(text, &response); err != nil {
    return Result{}, fmt.Errorf("Failed to JSON-decode response body, received %s from source, error was: %s", text, err)
}

fmt.Println(response.Result.BitsUsed)
fmt.Println(response.Result) // this prints!

return response.Result, response.Error
```

works, but changing these lines to just

```
response := ResponseBody{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(text, &response); err != nil {
    return Result{}, fmt.Errorf("Failed to JSON-decode response body, received %s from source, error was: %s", text, err)
}

fmt.Println(response.Result) // this no longer prints! :O

return response.Result, response.Error
```

causes `Request` function itself to hang at this debug statement.

## Things I've Tried

- Running a trace with `go test -trace` to view what's being called. This fails because `go tool trace` cannot parse the generated trace file.
- Converting my signature to return `*error` instead of regular `error`. This did not help.

---

Why is this code snippet hanging?

Note: I am running Go 1.7

Comment: Related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928744/an-infinite-loop-produced-by-fmt-sprinte-inside-the-error-method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474907/error-infinite-loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with the definition of `Error` interface. The function `Error() string` on `Error` type is recursively calling itself when you try to `fmt.Sprintf` the value `e`:

```
func (e Error) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Error: %+v", e) // calls e.Error again
}
```

Try to return error by accessing `Error` type's members explicitely:

```
func (e Error) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Error: %+v", e.Message)
}
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't see that. But [the Go docs say](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Printing) that `%+v` only prints the field names and the values. Why would the `Error` method be called as well? Are methods fields too?

Comment: @AkshatMahajan because standard formatting `%v` checks where methods like `String` or `Error` are implemented and then call them to format. And  `%+v` is detailed formatting: it does not use those methods and constructs output  on it own. The same with `%#v`. But using them is some sort of hack - you lose ability to use standard methods and short representation.

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky Thanks for the great explanation! Do you know if this is officially documented anywhere? Would be awesome to know where I should have looked next time.

Comment: The behaviour is documented after all verbs have been listed. The section explains special formatting considerations that apply for operants implementing certain interfaces. It is contained in the [fmt](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) documentation and can be found by searching for "formatting considerations". The 4th entry in the list is the one relevant to this question.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is recursion because `fmt` calls `Error()` what calls fmt again.

Classical solutions is to convert your error type into `string` and then use standard mechanics. This way you have all the formatting tools. Like:

```
type E string

func (e E) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf(string(e))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/NI5JL3H4g7Y

Excerpt from `fmt` [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) (unfortunatelly cannot make direct link to the paragraph):

> 4. If an operand implements the error interface, the Error method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any).
> 5. If an operand implements method String() string, that method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any).
>
> To avoid recursion in cases such as
>
> ```
> type X string 
>
> func (x X) String() string { return Sprintf("<%s>", x) }
> ```
>
> convert the value before recurring:
>
> ```
> func (x X) String() string { return Sprintf("<%s>", string(x)) }
> ```
>
> Infinite recursion can also be triggered by self-referential data
> structures, such as a slice that contains itself as an element, if
> that type has a String method. Such pathologies are rare, however, and
> the package does not protect against them.
>
> When printing a struct, fmt cannot and therefore does not invoke
> formatting methods such as Error or String on unexported fields.

Comment: Ah, this is great. Unfortunately I had to give the accepted answer to abhink because he answered first, but perhaps you can help me understand why `fmt` calls `Error()` internally. I thought `Sprintf("%+v", e)` only operates on the field names and values. Is this behaviour documented somewhere?

Comment: I've described it above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48021232/accessing-golang-struct-that-implements-error-interface-causes-function-to-never/48021499?noredirect=1#comment83012103_48021386